# “C'est bon, une rose” and “C'est bon, les roses”

Tags: grammaire, articles, pluriel

I want to know the difference between the following sentences:

> C'est bon, une rose.
>
> C'est bon, les roses.

What's the difference between using the singular and the plural in the sentence?

And do they mean the same?

Comment: I'd say they mean the same thing ("Roses are good") in most contexts. You might say, « C'est bon, une rose rouge, quand on veut faire preuve de son amour » or in other situations where it makes sense to distinguish between having a single rose and talking about roses in general.

Comment: I'd say using singular is maybe, maybe a little bit more elevated language, or for speech, or poetry.

Answer (score 4):

They mean the same thing: "Roses are good." The singular « une rose » still means roses in general.

The literal difference is more or less parallel to the English:

> C'est bon, une rose. *A rose is good.*
>   
> C'est bon, les roses. *Roses are good.*

Notice how the English sounds a little awkward. A rose is good? It sounds like an unfortunate mix between having a particular rose in mind and talking about roses in general.

In order to save the meaning of the English sentence, you need to qualify the situation:

> C'est bon, une rose, quand on veut être romantique.
>   
> *A rose is good when you want to be romantic.*

(Notice how this sentence would also be meaningful if you mean that a single rose would do.)

On the other hand, the plural is okay without any further context (though you certainly can provide some if needed).

I believe the French behaves similarly in this and similar sentences. Here's another one for fun...

> Un éléphant se conduit de façon irrationnelle. *An elephant acts irrationally.* (Which one?)
>   
> Un éléphant se conduit de façon irrationnelle en musth. *An elephant acts irrationally in musth.* (=all)

Comment: I kind of wish that OP had included a third example using the singular definite article so I could have maybe finally discovered exactly which rose Mr. Bécaud was singing about in “L'important c'est la rose” (although I suspect that simply admitting the need to come here to find that out probably means I’m missing something much more important than just some linguistic or botanical point)!

Comment: @PapaPoule :) I hadn't heard the song till now, but I think we need to understand an implicit « que tu la donnes » or something. Would that make sense there, do you think?

Comment: or maybe "que tu recois/que tu as" (more so than money/material things that one can give/receive/possess). or maybe just the general idea of "the rose" and all that it can mean

Comment: Ah, okay. There is definitely a basis for definite articles and general meanings, like *l'homme*, but I wonder how limited those cases are. (Also, why did I write *la donnes* instead of *lui donnes* ? Anyway...)

Comment: At least you didn't use "que tu **elle** donnes," which is how I'm often tempted to write such clauses, maybe because I find that "elle" is such a beautiful word that captures the beauty of women (even when they're being used as "mere [indirect] objects") so much more so than the default/unisex "lui"!

Comment: My family has some ties to India and Nepal, and my mom likes to tell the story of asking a Hindi speaker what he thought the most beautiful word in his language was. "Ohhh," he said, "that is the word for 'lady'. *Behgum! Behgum!* Beautiful." I agree that we're quite lucky to have *elle*.